# How can one configure exim still to reject invalid recipients after an earlier ACL returned "discard"?

Tags: email, smtp, exim, access-control-list

For the reasons set out in my earlier question [Originating (non-critical) emails from a "less-trusted" host](https://serverfault.com/q/683574), it unfortunately seems that we must run an SMTP server for the *sole purpose* of accepting and then immediately discarding bounce messages!

We would like to use Exim for this purpose.

To that end, I have placed the following in its `acl_smtp_mail` access control list:

```
discard senders = :
drop
```

Whilst this yields the desired behaviour in response to the SMTP `MAIL` command, Exim is now responding with `250 Accepted` to *all* `RCPT TO` commands.  We would like for it only to accept valid recipients, and reject invalid ones (so that clients do not get the erroneous impression that we're openly relaying messages).

**Why is Exim now accepting all recipients (it wasn't before the introduction of the above access list), and how can it now be configured to reject invalid recipients?**

Comment: While `deny` action explicitly inform sender that his message couldn't be accepted, `discard` action implicitly accept message and then drop them - more or less silently.

Comment: @Kondybas: Yes, but surely not at the expense of all future ACLs?  If `accept` were to indicate that, then such a response at an early stage of an SMTP transaction would immediately negative all subsequent access control!

Comment: I've used ACL-variables to store the state of the message all way long through the ACLs. In fact, I have `accept` and `warn` actions only, but when message finally falls into the routers, router checks the variables and deliver to the `inbox`, `spam`, `sa-learn` or `blackhole` correspondingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the following documented under [ACL return codes](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html#SECID196):

> If the ACL for MAIL returns “discard”, all recipients are discarded, and no ACL is run for subsequent RCPT commands.